# With an existing JSON file, how do I upload this data to BigQuery and calculate a new field with data in the JSON file?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a new-line delimited JSON file I'm going to be upload to BigQuery.

Each row of the JSON file contains many fields and I would like to add two of these together, to form a new column that contains both values added together.

However, there are millions of records, I would rather not use SQL to do this after the JSON has been fully uploaded.

Is there any process that can be done to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Maybe something in the JSON schema? Or maybe something in the way I upload the JSON and JSON schema to BigQuery?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: "I would rather not use SQL to do this after the JSON has been fully uploaded." Why? That would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Because this is a requirement placed upon me at the moment. I have a JSON file without a value I need in the database and I can't be adding the column using SQL afterwards. These are constraints I've been asked to work with unless I can report it is impossible to do otherwise.

Comment: You can't load and transform at the same time. Instead, you need to load the data and then transform it, or else define an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage) and run a query over it to write to a new table.

Comment: Thank you, that's sufficient an answer coming from a google employee. My boss seems satisfied that we have to approach it differently now. Thank you!

Comment: FYI JSON Schema does not do JSON transformations. JSON Schema is (mainly) for defining the structure of your JSON for validation purposes.

Comment: Would you be happy with a command line solution that you would need to run on the JSON file before upload?

Comment: That's what we'll be doing :)

Answer (score 0):

Check my "[lazy data loading in BigQuery](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6)" post:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

The trick is to set up BigQuery to look into the GCS files as federated CSV files with a rare character separator. Then you can do any transform within BigQuery itself.

In my case:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE VIEW `fh-bigquery.views.wikipedia_views_test_ddl`
AS SELECT
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S', REGEXP_EXTRACT(_FILE_NAME, '[0-9]+-[0-9]+')) datehour
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, '([^ ]*) ') wiki
  , REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, '[^ ]* (.*) [0-9]+ [0-9]+') title
  , CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, ' ([0-9]+) [0-9]+$') AS INT64) views
  , CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, ' ([0-9]+)$') AS INT64) zero
  , _FILE_NAME filename
  , line
FROM `fh-bigquery.views.wikipedia_views_gcs`WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, ' ([0-9]+) [0-9]+$') IS NOT NULL # views
AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, ' ([0-9]+)$') = '0' # zero
```

Instead of `REGEXP_EXTRACT` you could do `JSON_EXTRACT/JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`, or - for maximum flexibility - JavaScript UDFs.